# Output pdf map size issue when no simple fill solid symbology

Tags: qgis, symbology, pdf

The size of the output pdf map increases enormously when the symbol of a polygon isn't set to "simple fill" + "solid". A4 output results:

1. simple fill solid = 7 Ko
2. simple fill BDiagonal = 1'766 Ko
3. line pattern = 598 Ko

Does someone experiences the same problem and find a solution?

It seems that it isn't a vector/raster output pdf issue.

QGIS 2.14 and 2.18 produce the same output map size.

**Steps to reproduce the issue**

1. open qgis;
2. create New **polygon** Shapefile Layer;
3. select a 10'000 scale;
4. draw a simple polygon;
5. Project > New Print Composer > Page size A4 > Add new map;
6. Export as PDF (vector and then raster) with a simple fill solid symbology;
7. Export as PDF (vector and then raster) with a simple fill BDiagonal symbology;
8. Export as PDF (vector and then raster) with a Line pattern fill.

Comment: Do you need a vector PDF? If not, try to enable "print it as a raster" to get a PDF with a rasterized map.

Comment: The problem is I need a print quality output : a minimum export resolution of 300 dpi.
And the output raster results are even worse:

    1. simple fill solid = 8 Ko
    2. simple fill BDiagonal = 2'040 Ko
    3. line pattern = 703 Ko

Comment: The issue seems to refer to rasterized output pdf. 
See this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290254/exporting-point-pattern-fill-as-vector-data-in-pdf).
The problem seems to be experienced on version 2 and 3 of QGIS. 
Someone has managed to create a fully vectorized output with a virtual machine and Ubuntu [link](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/6996), but it's not really convenient...