# Exporting point pattern fill as vector data in PDF

Tags: qgis, vector, pdf, qgis-3

In QGIS 3.2, I have a map with parks/other green areas to be displayed as a simple vector point pattern fill. No matter what I do, the pattern fill is always exported to PDF as raster data, which is pretty annoying.

Any suggestions how to change this behaviour?

Comment: What have you already tried? Do you want to use a script oder just use print composer to export?

Comment: So far, I have only tried to export using the print composer. If there's a scripting solution, I would try it - but so far I don't have that much experience with scripting in QGIS...

Answer (score 2):

This isn't currently possible - point pattern and line pattern fills are always rasterised when rendered, regardless of the output type and settings. See https://issues.qgis.org/issues/6996.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you / us!

https://impermanent.io/2017/05/05/generative-pseudo-random-polygon-fill-patterns-in-qgis/

To make the code usable in QGIS 3, change in function editor the line 41 to QgsPoint**XY**(ptX,ptY), line 42 QgsGeometry.frompoint**XY**(pt) and line 46   return QgsGeometry.fromMultiPoint**XY**(points)

If you don't want randomness, set the third parameter to 0 of the new exrpression.

The output PDF pattern fill will be vectorized!