# How to create pattern fill via geomtry generator in QGIS3?

Tags: qgis, style, geometry-generator, qgis-3

I would like to style polygon layer using geometry generator to create point patterns but using just generated points geometry. Is it possible? How can I achieve that?

I know that I can use just use polygon geometry and choose points pattern fill but I don't want to use that option. I'm looking for workaround to create points pattern fill which remain vector when exported. In QGIS3 is a bug which prevent standard pattern fill to be exported as vector.

I genereted some lines or points inside polygon via geometry generator and they was exported as vector. So it should work but I lack experience to create regular pattern fill in geometry generator.

Comment: Creating points in geometry generator may not be the most efficient way to achieve your end goal. Why not create a point grid and clip it to the polygon geometry?

Comment: I need exported map in full vectors for print purpose. For very long time there is a bug in QGIS which rasterize points grid on export.

Comment: Not a point pattern fill. Use the `create grid` tool to create a point grid. A point grid is a separate vector layer.

Comment: see my answer here : <https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290254/exporting-point-pattern-fill-as-vector-data-in-pdf?noredirect=1&lq=1>